# How to access control's ID when 'this' is passed as argument to a function from an external js file

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have an asp button that calls a function from an external javascript file when it is clicked. The `this` keyword is passed as the argument. The purpose of this is for the function to retrieve the id of the control. The function will be reused by other buttons.

The problem is, when passing `this`, the object that is passed will contain the `ClientID` in which the external js function doesn't have an idea.

I don't want to hard code the ID like `OnClientClick="toggle('btnClick')"`. 
 My button control looks like this:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnClick" runat="server" OnClientClick="toggle(this); return false;"/>
```

And my external js function looks like this:

```
function toggle(button){
console.log(button);//currently, the id shown in console
                    //is the ClientID. I just want to get the "btnClick" ID
//do something about the button after retrieving the ID
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a setting in web.config now that will get rid of the ClientID problem. This will render the ID as it looks in the markup.

```
<system.web>
    <pages clientIDMode="Static">
</system.web>
```

And make sure you ask for `button.id`.

Comment: The `clientIDMode="Static"` is the solution. I put it in the button control and it works like a charm. Thanks a lot!